# Session are null but still going inside not null

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have a piece of code for which I am checking `Session` values.

So, while Inserting rows for the first time inside `gridview`, I am setting the `session`  value as `null` on `Page_load`.

But while debugging what happens here is, it still going inside condition where `Session` is checked as `not null`

Below is my code.

```
int iRowCountExp = 0;      
if (Session["ExpInfo"] != null)
{   
    dtExpInfo = (DataTable)Session["ExpInfo"];

    if (strMode == "M")
    {
        FunFillGridDetails();
        dtExpInfo = (DataTable)Session["ExpInfo"];
    }
}
else
{
    BindDataTable();
}
```

`Page_load` code

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
     Session["ExpInfo"] = null;
}
```

Comment: which name you are create Session["ExpInfo"]???

Comment: @DenishParvadia: sorry didn't got you.

Comment: check create session name and get value session name is same or not?

Comment: @DenishParvadia: yes they are same...I am checking for that only

Comment: also check session timeout?

Comment: yes, session time out is proper,

Comment: check if the session was accessed somewhere else before the `if` condition.

Comment: try Session["ExpInfo"] = string.Empty;

Comment: @DenishParvadia: It is giving me as `""`

Comment: `Session.Remove("ExpInfo")`

Comment: check session if (Session["ExpInfo"] != "")

Comment: @Backs: what should I do with that ?

Comment: @DenishParvadia: its returning me as `false`

Comment: @Backs: u  mean to say this ? `Session.Remove("ExpInfo");
        if (Session["ExpInfo"] != null)` ??

Comment: You said it. Use `Session.Remove("variableName");` to remove the session instead of setting its value to null.

Comment: @ViVi: can u ellaborate with some code as how to write it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Session.Remove(variableName)` deletes the entry (both key & value) from the dictionary. `Session[variableName] = null` assigns a value to the key in the dictionary(Value being `null`). So the value will only be null and the key will still exist. If you remove the variable using `Session.Remove(variableName)`, then the variable is deleted and your check will be successful. Hope you got the point.

Hence your code should be :

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
     Session.Remove("ExpInfo");
}
```

Comment: So on page load, there should be both code, session.remove and session [Expinfo] ??

Comment: Please read my answer again. Whenever you want to clear your session, use `Session.Remove()`. There is no need to set the value of the key to `null`, unless you want the key to exist with a value of `null`. @nad

Comment: If I add only one row in all the grid it works, but when I add more than one row it gives me error

Comment: what does a grid and its rows have to do in a session?

Comment: I am assigning values using session in the grid row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131565/discussion-between-nad-and-vivi).

Answer (score 0):

try this code working fine

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
         Session["ExpInfo"] = string.Empty;
          string value = Session["ExpInfo"] as string;
         if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
         {
           BindDataTable();
        }
        else
        {
             dtExpInfo = (DataTable)Session["ExpInfo"];
             if (strMode == "M")
             {
            FunFillGridDetails();
            dtExpInfo = (DataTable)Session["ExpInfo"];
            }
       }
    }
```

Comment: let me try and check

Comment: getting error as `Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'.` at `dtExpInfo = (DataTable)Session["ExpInfo"];`